# Jmeter remove empty strings at a SOAP/xml request

Tags: xml, csv, soap, jmeter

I am using "Jmeter with CSV and SOAP/xml request".
My tests are running within like 80 data sets and some fields in the CSV must be empty for testing issues.

My JMeter Build:
-ThreadGroup
   -CSV Data
   -SOAP/XML
     -XPathExtractor
 -Outcome

CSV like a matrix table, multiple rows and columns.

SOAP/XML

```
...
<attribute xsi:type="ns2:stringType" name = "freeText2">
<value>${freeText2}</value>
</attribute>
<attribute xsi:type="ns2:longType" name = "amount">
<value>${amount}</value>
</attribute>
...
```

My Problem:
When Jmeter has replaced the varibles:

```
<attribute xsi:type="ns2:stringType" name = "freeText2">
<value>This is my free Text</value>
</attribute>
<attribute xsi:type="ns2:longType" name = "amount">
<value>455667</value>
</attribute>
```

ALL IS FINE
BUT when some are empty

```
<attribute xsi:type="ns2:stringType" name = "freeText2">
<value></value> ==>interpreted as STRING
</attribute>
<attribute xsi:type="ns2:longType" name = "amount">
<value></value> ==>interpreted as STRING
</attribute>
```

The System tells me that "Long Amount with "" is not possible" and also i dont want to have in my System a freeText2 with "" empty String.

Now my Question:
Is there any way to wirte a adapter/handler/extractor...anything to get the Request empty String converted just to nothing (not Null because it will throw me a NullPointerException) like ==>

```
<attribute xsi:type="ns2:longType" name = "amount">
<value></value>
</attribute>
```

converted to

```
<attribute xsi:type="ns2:longType" name = "amount">

</attribute>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correctly getting your question and you need to get rid of empty values occurrences like remove all `<value></value>` elements it can be easily done using Beanshell.

1. Add a [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) **as a child** of problematic SOAP/XML-RPC Request
2. Insert the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   String data = sampler.getXmlData();
   data = data.replaceAll("<value></value>","");
   sampler.setXmlData(data);
   ```
3. Run your test

Beanshell Pre Processor is executed before request so it'll replace all occurrences of `<value></value>` with an empty string

You can refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for extended information on using Beanshell with Apache JMeter.