# JMeter - Remove empty elements in SOAP request

Tags: xml, csv, soap, jmeter, beanshell

I am using CSV Data Set Config to fill SOAP/XML variables to request in `JMeter`. My problem is, when some variables are empty, then i get error on validation caused by this so I need to get rid of those.

There is very similar topic, well described ([Jmeter remove empty strings at a SOAP/xml reqeust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041131/jmeter-remove-empty-strings-at-a-soap-xml-reqeust)), unfortunately the solution is not working for me, iam getting:

> meter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String data =
>   sampler.getXmlData(); data = data.replaceAll("","");  . . .
>   '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method
>   getXmlData() not found in
>   class'org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The referenced answer assumed [SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request), you're using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) so request data needs to be manipulated a little bit differently.

Change the line:

```
String data = sampler.getXmlData();
```

to:

```
String data = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
```

Again I encourage you to get yourself familiarised with [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Comment: Thank you, and what should I use instead sampler.setXmlData(data); ?
I tried sampler.setArguments(data); as described here:

https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#setArguments(org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments)

with the same result.

Thanks for your patience, Iam very new at all this stuff.

Comment: It's `sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(data);`, You should look at https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Argument.html#setValue(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

```
Method getXmlData() not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy'
```

Because this method exists in **SoapSampler**, not in "HTTPSamplerProxy"
https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/SoapSampler.html